# OpenCL 2.x(C++ bindings): undefined identifier

Tags: c++, opencl

**Edit:** adding OpenCL.lib in library files section of visual studio solved the problem.

With cl2.hpp from [this github repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/releases) pointed by khronos site, I get 60-70 similar errors when I try to compile a C++ dll project with OpenCL-C++-implementation functions to export.

```
'CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_ON_HOST_PROPERTIES': undeclared identifier
// I'm not using this, I'm newly converting a v1.2 C++ binding-based
// project to a v2.0 one
```

starting of the file is:

```
using namespace std;
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL\cl2.hpp>
```

and the remaining lines are not underlined with red(visual studio). There are some compile time constants I need to add maybe, but I don't know which constants.

What is missing?

this code(there isn't any other code in project) also gives same error:

```
#include <CL\cl2.hpp>
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` looks suspicious. You really shouldn't do stuff like that anyway.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious cl2.hpp uses "string" without std prefix and gives errors on more locations when I don't write that, but yes it looks bad.

Comment: So your solution is to add `using namespace std` before other headers that _don't_ require it?

Comment: More like a fix in a hurry. I will restructure later. Project doesn't even use < thread > if I remember correctly. Okay, deleted irrelevant parts now.

Comment: I used cl2.hpp in the past and have never experienced such compilation problems. Maybe some #define's from 1.2 project you are using are creating these problems?. Maybe you can post [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Btw cl2.hpp is creating alias: `using string = std::string;` so `using namespace std;` isn't necessary unless you are messing up with `CL_HPP_NO_STD_STRING`. Also you can try to #include first cl headers and then std ones: `#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` then
`#include <CL/cl.hpp>` and then `#include <vector>` ...

Comment: @doqtor with only `#include <CL\cl2.hpp>` and nothing else as a new project, it gives same error.

Comment: It requires C++11. Do you have it enabled? What compiler are you using? For gcc that is just: `g++ -I/opt --std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -lOpenCL` that is required to successfully built it (I put latest cl2.hpp in /opt/CL for this test).

Comment: @doqtor it raised a warning for c++11 as unknown. Also visual studio 2015 is using c++14 or newer.

Comment: I don't have VS2015 to try but it works fine with VS2017. Do you have VS2015 Update 3? It's not that VS2015 has absolutely everything implemented from c++11 but Update 3 has it quite well [covered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance). Maybe you can post the error output?

Comment: @doqtor OpenCL.lib was missing in library files. That fixed this. But why would 'CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_ON_HOST_PROPERTIES' not be identified because of a missing lib, 'CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_ON_HOST_PROPERTIES' is defined in hpp file already, maybe there is a conditional definition with absence of that library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same errors and something that worked for me was to add the following prior to `#include <cl2.hpp>`

```
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#include <cl2.hpp>
```